# Can Selenium WebDriver automate Firefox toolbars?

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon, automated-tests

I am trying to build test automation for toolbars built for Firefox browser.
I am wondering if Selenium WebDriver is the correct tool for the job.

Based on the documentation found on Selenium webpage, it seems that Selenium is built to interact with webpages and doesn't have the capability to interact with browser components (a toolbar for example.).

Please correct me if I am mistaken and if possible provide the name of a tool to automate toolbar testing if such a tool exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this [Sikuli](https://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver) .

This can be used with your selenium test cases.

Updated:

[Sikuli](https://launchpad.net/sikuli/+download)

Comment: Dead link. Please fix or add content to your answer

Answer (score 0):

One choice for Windows is [White](https://github.com/TestStack/White) automation framework. 
For instance, how to start work with White, take a look at my answer: 
 [How to validate a messagebox popup in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23546232/how-to-validate-a-messagebox-popup-in-c/23553516#23553516)

Comment: Thanks, will make sure to have a look at it.